# How to test if my package is modifying the Global Environment in R?

Tags: r, environment, r-package

I'm trying to submit a package to CRAN. After the manual check, they send this warning:

> Please do not modifiy the .GlobalEnv. This is not allowed by the CRAN
> policies. Please set all standard values regarding the environment to a
> different environment than the .GlobalEnv.

My package passed the CRAN checks on the three operative systems (GitHub Actions), and I checked that all the `assign()` and `eval()` calls use a new environment created inside the function. So far, I don't see new objects in the .GlobalEnv.

How can I test that my package is modifying the .GlobalEnv? and which code is the culprit?

Comment: is `devtools::check()` throwing any notes regarding this issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: then maybe just ask them which note they received or how they noticed it. I would just add a few sentences to show that you understood what they said and tried to fix it